# How can I stop the react-router-dom <Prompt> from appearing when I submit a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am implementing a warning dialog when a user tries to navigate away from a form after they've entered information. When navigating to a page that uses react-router, I have a custom warning dialog. When navigating to non-react-router pages or using the browser back/reload buttons, I have it set to show the standard browser warning dialog.

It all works as expected EXCEPT when you click the submit button on the form. Because the dialog is being generated when the form is dirty, it's still appearing on submit. I'm looking for a way to indicate that when the user submits, the prompt is not activated.

I've tried using some different conditionals that trigger the dialog (or not), e.g., `formIsDirty && formIsSubmitting`, but this makes the dialog appear whenever the form is not submitting.

I am using: `react 16.13.1` and `react-router-dom 5.2.0`

This is the whole component. When I use it within a form, I use `!isPristine` from redux-form as the conditional for the `when` prop of `<Prompt>`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { useHistory, Prompt } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
import WarningDialog from 'src/components/WarningDialog';

export default function ExitDialog({ isDirty }) {
  const history = useHistory();
  const nextLocation = useRef();
  const [showExitDialog, setShowExitDialog] = useState(false);

  const cancelNavigation = () => { setShowExitDialog(false); };

  const handleBlockedNavigation = (location) => {
    setShowExitDialog(true);
    nextLocation.current = location;
    return false;
  };

  const confirmNavigation = () => {
    setShowExitDialog(false);
    if (nextLocation.current) { // Navigate to the previous blocked location
      history.push(nextLocation.current);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // to handle navigation to Plan10 pages, using the back/forward or refresh in the browser
    function navHandler(e) {
      // Cancel the event
      e.preventDefault();
      // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
      e.returnValue = '';
    }
    if (isDirty) {
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', navHandler);
    }
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', navHandler);
    };
  }, [isDirty]);

  return (
    <>
      <Prompt when={isDirty && !showExitDialog} message={handleBlockedNavigation} />
      <WarningDialog
        alertMessage={<FormattedMessage id="admin_home.smartReports.exit_without_saving_title" />}
        applyLabel={<FormattedMessage id="buttons.exit" />}
        cancelLabel={<FormattedMessage id="buttons.continue_editing" />}
        open={showExitDialog}
        data-test-id="exitDialog"
        handleClose={cancelNavigation}
        handleApply={confirmNavigation}
        disableBackdropClick
      >
        <FormattedMessage id="admin_home.smartReports.exit_without_saving_contents" />
      </WarningDialog>
    </>
  );
}

ExitDialog.propTypes = {
  isDirty: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};
```